# Using Jasmine to spy on document.createElement throws error from angular mock

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-mock

I have an Angular service that handles the webcam. Here is the function I'm trying to test:

```
this.takePicture = function() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;

    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(this.videoElement, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);

    return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 100);
};
```

I'm trying to mock the call to document.createElement and return a fake canvas object. Here is my test:

```
it('should draw an image', function() {
    var drawImageSpy = jasmine.createSpy('drawImage');

    var canvas = {
        getContext: jasmine.createSpy('getContext').and.returnValue({ drawImage: drawImageSpy }),
        width: 0,
        height: 0,
        toDataURL: jasmine.createSpy('toDataUrl').and.returnValue('data-uri')
    };

    document.createElement = jasmine.createSpy('createCanvas').and.returnValue(canvas);

    WcCameraService.takePicture();

    expect(drawImageSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at TypeError (native)
    at Function.jQuery.extend.buildFragment (C:/Projects/Accurev/WebCOE_FRF_DEV/src/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5565:24)
    at Function.jQuery.parseHTML (C:/Projects/Accurev/WebCOE_FRF_DEV/src/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:9923:18)
    at jQuery.fn.init (C:/Projects/Accurev/WebCOE_FRF_DEV/src/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:2774:33)
    at Object.jQuery [as element] (C:/Projects/Accurev/WebCOE_FRF_DEV/src/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js:73:10)
    at $get (C:/Projects/Accurev/WebCOE_FRF_DEV/src/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.min.js:6:18224)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (C:/Projects/Accurev/WebCOE_FRF_DEV/src/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:39:193)
    at C:/Projects/Accurev/WebCOE_FRF_DEV/src/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:41:10
    at Object.d [as get] (C:/Projects/Accurev/WebCOE_FRF_DEV/src/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:38:394)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:/Projects/Accurev/WebCOE_FRF_DEV/src/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.min.js:6:21105)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I was looking in angular-mocks and it seems to be failing at this point:

```
if (window.jasmine || window.mocha) {

...

  if (injector) {
    injector.get('$rootElement').off();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, document.createElement is immutable. You really shouldn't be spying on it in the first place. It's a built-in function that will perform the same way every time. Your other spies look fine.

Answer (score 0):

Its kind of weird to spy on that. But -in greater versions of angular- you can accomplish it by just spying into the `createElement` method. You can join this with a `returnValue` with a jasmine spy to expect certain calls. Like this:

```
const toDataUrlSpy = jasmine.createSpy('dataUrl');
spyOn(document, 'createElement').and.returnValue({
  width: 0,
  height: '',
  getContext: () => ({ drawImage: () => {} })
  toDataURL: toDataUrlSpy
});

service.takePicture();
expect(toDataUrlSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and have solved it by using both `callThrough()` and `withArgs()` methods to only spy my specific case and let other calls to be done normally.

When you spy a method of the document object, you alter every calls that could be done by other part of your code or vendors' codes. Using `withArgs()`, you limit the side effects.

Here is my example (I was trying to test a modal that download a file from a text built in the web page) :

```
var fakeElement = {
    setAttribute: function (name, value) { fakeElement[name] = value; },
    click: function () {}
};
spyOn(fakeElement, 'click');
spyOn(document, 'createElement').and.callThrough().withArgs('a').and.returnValue(fakeElement);
spyOn(document.body, 'appendChild').and.callThrough().withArgs(fakeElement);
spyOn(document.body, 'removeChild').and.callThrough().withArgs(fakeElement);
```